# ObjectInputStream no muestra correctamente los datos del objeto

Tags: java, string, object, objeto

Quiero un programa que lea un fichero serializado que contiene los datos de un objeto llamado "Comarca": por un lado tiene strings(comarq) y por otro ints(poblacio). El nombre del fichero hay que pasarlo por parámetro (vaya, por el args del main). El programa en su mayoría funciona bien, pero no me muestra los datos correctamente.

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
public class LlegirFitxerObject {

public static FileInputStream fitxerALlegir = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        verificacioEntrada(args);
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No se puede volver a leer el fichero.");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void verificacioEntrada(String[] args) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, IOException, FileNotFoundException,
        ClassNotFoundException {

    if (args.length == 0) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("ERROR");
    }

    if (args.length > 1) {
        throw new IOException("ERROR).");
    }

    fitxerALlegir = new FileInputStream(args[0]);

    ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(fitxerALlegir);
    Object aux = input.readObject();

    while (aux != null) {
        if (aux instanceof Comarca) {
            System.out.println(aux);
        }
        aux = input.readObject();
    }
    input.close();

}
```

}

Comment: Has tratado de obtener los valores de las variables del objeto utilizando los metodo `get` de estas: `aux.getComarq()` y `aux.getPoblacio()`.

Comment: Debería sobrescribir el método `toString` de la clase `Comarca` y darle el formato para que muestre los atributos respectivos. o acceder directamente a los atributos a través de los `getters` como menciona David

Comment: Efectivamente David el problema era que no tenía ningún get! Gracias. He editado mi pregunta ya que ahora tengo el problema de que, si bien sale el contenido del fichero, cada dato aparece repetido 9 veces (que es justamente cada dato que contiene, en total hay 9, pues esos 9 aparecen repetidos 9 veces cada uno de ellos). Raro raro.

Comment: No reparo eches una pregunta para hacer otra, las respuestas pasan a ser incorrectas con tu edición. Crea una nueva pregunta si tienes un nuevo problema

Comment: Ok, mis disculpas. Soy nuevo por aquí.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas el método

```
System.out.println(Object objeto);
```

Haces el equivalente a:

```
System.out.println(objeto.toString());
```

Si tu clase no ha implementado ese método, sobreescribiendo [el que implementa Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), lo único que verás es la impresión de:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
```

Así que tu problema se resuelve creando un método `String toString() {...}` en tu clase Comarca