# ¿Como guardar parametros en un array de objeto?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Estoy haciendo este programa

```
import java.util.*;
public class gestionDesposito {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tamanio=0;
    String identificador="00001";
    double lado=1000;
    double alto=500;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Escriba el numero de despositos a crear entre 4 y 10: ");
  tamanio=sc.nextInt();                                                           //Se pone la asignacion de tamaño justo despues por que sino estariamos creando un array de longitud 1
  Deposito[] d=new Deposito[tamanio];
  if(tamanio>=4 && tamanio<=10){
      for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++){
         d[i]=new Deposito(identificador,lado,alto);
          System.out.println(d[i]);
          lado=lado+1000;
          alto=alto+500;
      }

  }

  sc.close();
}

}
```

Al ejecutar da esto 
`Escriba el numero de despositos a crear entre 4 y 10: 
8
Deposito@66d3c617
Deposito@63947c6b
Deposito@2b193f2d
Deposito@355da254
Deposito@4dc63996
Deposito@d716361
Deposito@6ff3c5b5
Deposito@3764951d`

Se que es por que no consigo guardar los parámetros en el array correctamente, pero no se como arreglarlo.
Mi clase es esta:

```
public class Deposito {
//variables nativas de la clase
private String identificador;
double litros;
private double capacidad;

//constructor
public Deposito(String identificador, double lado, double altura ){
    this.identificador=identificador;
    capacidad=lado*lado*altura*1000;
}

//metodos
public double getCapacidad(){
    return capacidad;

}
public double getLitros(){

    return litros;

}
public String getIdentificador(){
    return identificador;

}

public boolean estaLleno(){

    return capacidad==litros;
}
public boolean estaVacio(){

    return litros==0;
}   




public double aniadir(double litros){
    double diferencia=capacidad-this.litros;
    if(litros>0){
     if(litros<diferencia){
         this.litros=this.litros+litros;


     }
     else 
        this.litros=capacidad;
    }
    else 
        return -1;

    return this.litros;

}

public double vaciar(){
    double litros;
    litros=this.litros;
    this.litros=0;
    return litros;
}
public double vaciar(double litros){
    double diferencia=this.litros-litros;
    if(litros>0){
     if(diferencia>0){
         this.litros=this.litros-litros;
     }
     else
         return this.litros;
    }
    else
        return -1;

    return this.litros;

}



}
```

Comment: Te muestra esos valores porque estás imprimiendo un objeto Depósito y un objeto no se imprime así. O imprimes una de sus propiedades o sobreescribes su método toString para poder mostrar lo que tu quieras

Comment: Otra coas más, no modificas el identificador del depósito, se te van a generar todos los depósitos con el mismo identificador

Comment: Lo que pretendo hacer es ir rellenando las posiciones del array de d de tipo deposito con identificador, lado y alto, y luego mostrar todos los depósitos creados por pantalla con sus propiedades, y si, tampoco se modificar el string identificador para que vaya aumentando de 1 en 1.

Comment: Lo dicho, el problema es que haces System.out.println(d[i]); Prueba a hacer System.out.println(d[i].getLitros()); y verás que si que te los rellena bien.

Comment: Relacionada, por no decir duplicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105305/objectinputstream-no-muestra-correctamente-los-datos-del-objeto/105358#105358

Answer (score 2):

Cuando queres imprimir un objeto guardado en un array, no lo podes imprimir directamente. Esas lineas que te salen cuando intentas mostrar d[i], son direcciones de memoria donde se guarda cada objeto.

La forma correcta es mostrar cada uno de los atributos del objeto que se encuntra en la posicion 'i':

```
  for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++){
     d[i]=new Deposito(identificador,lado,alto);
      System.out.println(d[i].getCapacidad());
      System.out.println(d[i].getLitros());
      System.out.println(d[i].getIdentificador());
      lado=lado+1000;
      alto=alto+500;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad los valores los estas almacenado correctamente, lo que pasa es que al imprimir el objeto no estas imprimiendo su contenido, si no su referencia.

```
System.out.println(d[i]);

// Imprime:
Deposito@66d3c617
```

Para imprimir el contenido del objeto tienes dos opciones:

1. Accedes a las variables del objeto a través de los métodos `get` para obtener sus valores

   ```
   System.out.println(d[i].getIdentificador());
   System.out.println(d[i].getCapacidad());

   // Imprime:
   0001
   1000
   ```
2. Sobrescribe el método `toString()` en tu objeto y dentro de el retorna un `String` con los valores que quieres que retorne. Cuando imprimes un objeto, el método `toString()` se llama por defecto, y si no lo has sobrescrito este retorna la referencia del objeto, como en tu caso. En el método toString() se suele retornar el valor de las variables del objeto, pero, en el puedes retornar lo que quieras.

   ```
   public class Deposito {

       //variables nativas de la clase
       private String identificador;
       double litros;
       private double capacidad;

       //constructor
       public Deposito(String identificador, double lado, double altura ){
           this.identificador=identificador;
           capacidad=lado*lado*altura*1000;
       }

       // METODOS GET y SET
       ...

       // METODOS DEL OBJETO
       ...

       // Sobrescribes el método toString()
       @Override
       public String toString() {

           return "Id: " +identificador+ " Capacidad:" +capacidad+ "";

       }
   }
   ```

   Cuando imprimas el objeto obtendrás lo siguiente:

   ```
   System.out.println(d[i]);

   // Imprime:
   Id: 0001 Capacidad: 1000
   ```